# bind same event on two variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var office = $('#gameid') || $('#netid'); 

//$("#gameid" && "#netid").on('change', function(){


office.on('change', function(){
```

I want that if there is a change between one of the `var office`, then the function will be there is one event.

How to do that?

Comment: `.on` doesn't trigger events, it binds events.

Comment: Please learn some basic syntax. `x || y` returns `x` if it's true, otherwise it returns `y`. Why would you expect it to combine them?

Answer (score 6):

Try using [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) function to club the both,

```
var office = $('#gameid').add($('#netid')) 
office.on('change', function(){
```

Apart from the solution, i just need to comment on what you tried,

```
var office = $('#gameid') || $('#netid');
```

The above code of yours always return `$('#gameid')` to the variable office, because Jquery object is basically a collection. And it won't be undefined/falsy at any point of time.

Answer (score 5):

Use `,` to pass [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#gameid, #netid").on('change', function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('#gameid, #netid').on('change', function() { ... })
```